# Heroku App crashed. stty icanon echo (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: java, heroku, deployment

I build successfully my java app in heroku and also the deployment. When I open the app gives me an Application Error and in the logs says

> State changed from starting to crashed
>
> Process exited with status 127
>
> C:/Users/Alex/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:45:in ``':
>   No such file or directory - stty icanon echo (Errno::ENOENT)
>
> ```
>     from C:/Users/Alex/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:45:in `rescue in start'
>     from C:/Users/Alex/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:35:in `start'
>     from C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
> ```

The heroku version I use is

> heroku/toolbelt/3.30.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3

I've changed the

> File.join(Heroku::Helpers.home_directory, ".heroku",
>   "autoupdate.last") to "C:/Users/Alex/"

of the updater.rb but nothing changed. Any help please.

Comment: It looks like this was a bug in the Heroku Toolbelt. Did you get it resolved?

Comment: I'm still talking with them to solve it but not yet.